# Perform action when Excel sheet is changed - Office.js

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm trying to perform an action (specifically reapply filters on tables) when the active worksheet is changed in a workbook. This is using the Office.js API for an Excel Add-in. I noticed this question was asked several months ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756720/how-to-identify-the-excel-sheet-changed-event-in-office-js-api), and I'm wondering how to accomplish this with the latest production API set. I'm assuming this uses Bindings?

Answer (score 1):

I think the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756720/how-to-identify-the-excel-sheet-changed-event-in-office-js-api) holds good now. We're working on adding new events support including worksheet related events. However, it will take some time for it to be available.