# Attaching an handler to DocumentSelectionChanged event disables the Undo stack on Office for Mac

Tags: javascript, office-js

We have run in to, what seems like, a bug in Office.js on **Office for Mac**.

If you attach an event handler to `DocumentSelectionChanged` event that calls `Excel.run` the standard Excel "undo" functionality gets disabled. And this remains disabled until the add-in is unloaded (i.e. the event handler is unhooked).

You can replicate this problem by (for example), taking the `Excel-Add-in-JS-CollegeCreditsTracker` sample app and inserting the following block of code in `app.initialize` method.

```js
Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(
        Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged,
        function () {
            Excel.run(function (ctx) {
                var activeCell = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
                activeCell.load(["address", "worksheet", "rowIndex", "columnIndex", "values", "formulas"]);
                return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                    app.showNotification(activeCell.address);
                });
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        },
        null,
        function (asyncResult) {
            console.log("Handler added: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
        }
    );
```

Note that this works fine on Excel Desktop an Excel Online.
Is there a specific reason, such as API version supported on Office for Mac, that this would be failing?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39757568/157552) on an unrelated question suggests that there's an alternative way to handle selection change in newer API versions (although it doesn't say how). In which case, is that a possible workaround for this?

We cannot use BindingChanged events because we want to know when the user moves in and out of bindings, when user switches worksheets etc.

Comment: I have updated the answer on the other thread.  Would be curious to learn whether the new syntax solves the issue (though I assume it's merely syntactic, and shouldn't impact the underlying issue, if there is in fact a platform bug here).  But do let us know...

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Yes, as expected that didn't have any impact on the issue. Is this an issue that your team can take a look at?

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking this. Yes, I will pass it along to the team.

Comment: thanks for reporting this, we are investigating the issue internally, its apparently a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to let everyone know that this issue has been resolved by the Office team.