# onScroll event in office Word javascript API

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I know how to subscribe to selection change events in the office Word API for my addin (see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/read-and-write-data-to-the-active-selection-in-a-document-or-spreadsheet or [Microsoft Word JavaScript API - event handler for text selection in document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157240/microsoft-word-javascript-api-event-handler-for-text-selection-in-document)), but I cannot figure out how to subscribe to scroll events i.e. where the cursor is not moved. Do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll events are not yet supported in the Office JavaScript library. But it is a good idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).